# Set ownership of house in Skyrim Special Edition

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim Special Edition How do I set house ownership for a house (mods ex: Brisheim outside Whiterun, Riverwood Lakehouse outside Riverwood) and get full functionality (wife, kids move-in)?

If I ask Lucia if she wants to be adopted she asks: “do you have a house?”  player script says no even though I have a house.

Answer (score 1):

Some housing mods may have been released before Hearthfire was which allowed for adopting children as such wont support that.

Your best bet is to check if a mod says it supports Hearthfire.

- if it does then the mod should detail what you do to have your wife and children move in
- if it doesn't if it doesn't ask the mod owner if there is support and maybe request it

an alternative is to use another mod that sets a player's home. i don't recall the names of the mods i'm using but i have one that sets a house between Whiterun and where you face your first Dragon. while this mod supports stuff from the expansions (Hearthfire, Dragonball, Dawnguard) it doesn't really have support for moving in your wife and children. the mod creator however suggested another mod which gives you a spell that sets the mod home as the player's so your wife and kids know where to go (though one girl in Windhelm is bugged and wont go to any home from what i have read).

the Vanilla Houses you can buy in the original game and the ones you can build thanks to Hearthfire should work regardless one you have brought/built them, so long as you have Hearthfire installed (remember that Hearthfire is an optional expansion, some versions of Skyrim don't come with it) however since you're being asked if you do have a home that should mean that the adoption mechanic added by Hearthfire is working

Answer (score 0):

Well. You can buy a house, but you need to buy bedroom furnishing and a child's bedroom (from the same steward you bought the house from) before people can live there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and welcome on Arqade! Unfortunately, I think that you do not really answer the question, and add nothing to the existing answer.
I advise you to read the [Tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour), in order to learn how the site works, and how you can make it better.
Cheers!